# Related post based on content

Tags: query

I saw a lot of ways about related post but it's based on taxonomies.

I need help to display related post based on content in the single.php

Thanks

Comment: “Based on content” in what way?

Comment: @JacobPeattie percentage of the content like amount of words that exist on post content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm too low level to comment but maybe [this WP guide](https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/get-related-posts-based-on-the-posts-content-in-wordpress/) can help you.

I didn't want to copy and paste their answer in case it was against WPSE.

Comment: Wow. It looks like this is what I'm lookin for. Thank you